# Unable to tap on switch inside webView for ios hybrid app

Tags: ios-ui-automation

currently i am working with the hybrid ios app which contains the webview, inside the webview there is a switch(checkbox), this switch contains two links in it's name. So, whenever i am trying to tap on this switch one of the link gets tapped and navigates me to the next page.So, is there any way to tap on this particular switch(checkbox).?